# How to extract the access_token from url of Mailchimp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, mailchimp

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/Mailchimp/Access#access_token=^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^&expires_in=0
```

This is my mailchimp url , how to extract the access_token through java

and there another way to get the access token but here getting response message - Bad Request

```
URL siteUrl = new URL("https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        String content = "?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=^^^^^^^^^^&client_secret=^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^&code="+auth_code+"&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/Mailchimp/Access";

        out.writeBytes(content);
        System.out.println(content);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
```

Comment: getting code parameter from servlet response i.e. code=auth_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part after the # is called the "fragment" or "reference". This is a basic way to extract the relevant part:

```
public static String getAccessToken(String uriString) {
    URI uri = URI.create(uriString);
    String[] parameters = uri.getFragment().split("\\&");
    for (String parameter : parameters) {
        String[] parts = parameter.split("\\=");
        if (parts[0].equals("access_token")) {
            if (parts.length == 1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("missing access token");
            }
            return parts[1];
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("no access token");
}
```